# In Python's urllib, how can we get a URL which is updated after the call?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to scrape a webpage. However, when I make the call (using urllib2 + Python 3.4) in a browser, the URL changes to a unique one based on GUID every time a fresh call is made. For eg. if I make the call http://www..com, it changes to **http://www..com/DYNAMIC/id={GUID like string}**. All subsequent calls to links on the page have this ID appended to the calls. The GUID like string changes every time the browser is called. Is there a way to get the dynamic link with the GUID like string after a call to the site ? I am trying to make my script unobtrusive so I want to do this in a headless way (avoid using Selenium, for example).

Comment: Almost sure you'll need to build a custom Http Opener, something like `urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler`, `urllib.request.HTTPHandler`. Also may be you want to register a urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor...

Answer (score 1):

The [`.geturl()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) method exists precisely for this purpose:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
print urlopen(url).geturl()
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not seem to work. A call to urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.<site>.com').geturl() does get to an intermediate URL - http://www.<site>.com/DYNAMIC but that's it. But a further call to .geturl() using this does not go any further. The URL, when opened in a browser, looks something like this - http://www.<site>.com/DYNAMIC/index.asp?CartId={GUID string} ..... Maybe the index.asp may have something to do with this ?

Comment: @user1554876 Hmm, maybe you have to send cookies with your request... Or maybe there's JavaScript involved, in which case you'll have to use Selenium.